# Execute Java script code from CodeIgniter Controller

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

In my `CodeIgniter` controller every `Ajax` request checks the token I Passed. If any thing happens wrong I wrote a controller function to destroy all session and logout

```
 'redirect('main/logincontent/load_logout');'
```

In **load_logout** function

function load_logout()
        {

```
echo "<script>var c=confirm('do you want to continue?');
 if(c==true)
      {

      }
      else
     {</script>";
      $this -> session -> sess_destroy();
     echo "<script>window.parent.location.href ='" . base_url() . "';
     }</script>";
  }
```

I tried put a confirm box at the beginning of the function  `load_logout()`. Based on confirm box result user can decide whether to `destroy session` and logout or `stay Online`.

But it is not working!!!

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to close script tag each time, try this

```
  echo "<script>var c=confirm('do you want to continue?');
  if(c==true){}else{";
  $this -> session -> sess_destroy();
  echo "window.parent.location.href ='" . base_url() . "';
  }</script>";
```

but it is impossible to destroy session from client side. What you are doing here is just printing these details in client browser. But $this -> session -> sess_destroy(); will not work in browser, because it is server code. You need to add a route to destroy session and call that.